# .net core 3.1 deployed on linux ubuntu sql connection

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

I have mvc .net core 3.1 deployed on Ubuntu Linux 20.10 with Sql Express installed on Linux. The site is loading but I don't have a connection to the MS SQL. I tried many connection strings but all fail.
I tried to add this line to app.service

Environment=ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection={Connection String}

Also didn't work
The app is published as self-contained for linux.

The Connection in startup.cs

```
 var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<UniGateContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

the connection string in appsettings.json

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

and I tried this too

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;User ID=sa; Password=tttttt;"
  },
```

I am not using docker in my linux
The app works smoothly in IIS without any issue.
In Linux I am using Nginx

Site Loads, but when I enter my credentials it's not working, anonymous API access works but without results from the database.

any idea?

Comment: All we know from your post is that you cannot connect with a connection string we can't see and a code line you've placed somewhere. What error do you get? From where do you read the connection string? appsettings? environment variable? How does the code in your app service look like exactly? ...

Comment: I edited the post :)

Comment: When you try to access data from database, is there any error (try to use F12 developer Console or Network tool to check it)?

Comment: First of all, I'd ensure you have the correct data to build your connection string. That said: Try to connect to your SQL server manually to verify you know the correct host, username and password. You can do so, e.g. using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The SQL is working on Linux, I can login, create database and connect from MSSM Windows version.
Do I need Docker?

Comment: @ZhiLv No Error, I can access it from Microsoft SQL Management from Windows OS. 
The Same app is working in my Windows Server without any issue.